# PHP Friendly URL .htaccess Allowing Infinite URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, url-routing

When i type localhost/myproject/**about**/**garbage**/**blababla**/**about**/**qwertyu**/**adsfgad**/**about**

It WORKS (beacause my code only reads the last entry (about)), but... previous entries remain in the url (**about**/**garbage**/**blababla**/**about**/**qwertyu**/**adsfgad**)

When i try this on wordpress, the framework also pick the last entry, but rewrite url removing previous garbage

How to erase previous user entries garbages?

My Route code

```
define('ROUTE', basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
define('ROOT', basename(dirname(__DIR__)));
switch (ROUTE)
{
    case ROOT:
        require_once __DIR__.'/view/login.php';
        break;
    case 'about':
        require_once __DIR__.'/view/about.php';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        break;
};
```

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)